# Update div (&PHP variable) upon success of ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session-variables

I have an ajax function that is working. I have pasted the onComplete piece of the function below. It correctly returns the image in the following class(es): .paidpromopic .paidpromo-image .thumb.

```
        onComplete: function (filename, json) {
            if (json.error) {
                App.error(json.error);
                $('.paidpromopic .paidpromo-image .thumb').show();
            } else if (json.success) {
                var image = new Image();
                image.src = json.success;
                image.onload = function () {
                    $('.paidpromopic .paidpromo-image .thumb').attr('src', image.src).show();
                    $('.avatar-next').show();
                }


        [HERE IS WHERE I'M HOPING TO WRITE ONE LINE TO UPDATE $currentimage]

        }
```

Following (.paidpromopic .paidpromo-image .thumb), I have a div (id="new_image_name").  Inside that div, I have the variable $currentimage.

I would like to update the variable $currentimage. The php function called by the ajax function creates a session variable named 'newimage_name'.  In the same php function, I have also set $currentimage = 'newimage_name'.

Is there are line of code I can include in the onComplete piece above that will update div id="new_image_name"

Comment: If your app stays on that page and doesn't reload, then you can update the session variable in the PHP code, but you will need to use javascript (or jquery) on the client to update the div. PHP will already have been evaluated to render the original page and you won't be able to change that on the page.

Comment: Tx @Luke. Yes, the variable is already updated in the php code. What I am having trouble doing (or what I am not sure if I even can do) is getting the updated variable in the ajax onComplete function.  I have tried to create  var currentimage = $currentimage but I just dont know ajax very well. I am hoping there would be one line of code to add in there that will access the updated variable from the php function. Tx.

Comment: You will need to return the PHP variable inside the response of the AJAX request. Or do a separate request for the updated variable. I believe the first option is preferable.